# How to convert Dataframe to Map with key as one of column value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie in Spark/Scala and my problem statement is
I have a dataframe like below:

```
Col1 | Col2
a      1
a      2
a      3
b      4
b      5
```

i want to create a map like this

```
a-> [1,2,3]
b-> [4,5]
```

I am facing issue in combining col2 values based on col1 value and then creating a map with key as col1 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a",1),
  ("a",2),
  ("a",3),
  ("b",4),
  ("b",5)
).toDF("col1","col2")



val map: Map[String, Seq[Int]] = df.groupBy($"col1")
  .agg(collect_list($"col2"))
  .as[(String,Seq[Int])]
  .collect().toMap
```

gives

```
Map(b -> List(4, 5), a -> List(1, 2, 3))
```

But be aware that will blow up for large datasets

Comment: Which of the operation in this can blow up for large dataset? What do you recommend for a large dataset?

Comment: @DeveshKumar `collect`, as it brings all the data to the driver

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` with `collect_list`.

```
val aggdf = df.groupBy($"col1").agg(map($"col1",collect_list($"col2")).alias("mapped"))
aggdf.select($"mapped").show()
```

Comment: I'm confused, how is this a `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
val x = df.withColumn("x", array("col2"))
    .groupBy("col1")
    .agg(collect_list("x"))

x.show()

+----+---------------+
|col1|collect_list(x)|
+----+---------------+
|   b|     [[4], [5]]|
|   a|[[1], [2], [3]]|
+----+---------------+
```

Not really as you wanted, but we are a step closer :)